# HTTP Client Library AuthenticationHeaderValue

Tags: c#, windows-8, httpclient

I'm currently programming an application for windows 8, more precisely a PCL which I integrated Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries and Microsoft Async NuGet Package.

But it's not the problem. In fact, I need to customize Authorization Header of my request, but i got some exception beacuse i can't specify it like I need.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://url");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", USER_AGENT);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", token);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("", token);
```

My token is like that :

```
token = "0123456:123:0ea0e088090140af0ae05dca02d4c00c";
```

And I need to have the following Header :

```
Authorization: 0123456:123:0ea0e088090140af0ae05dca02d4c00c
```

But AuthenticationHeaderValue doesn't let me not specify his scheme, and if I set it with anything else the server isn't be able to correctly answer me.

If anyone can help me, I must be really grateful.

PS: I use a website API, so I can't modify identification protocol.

Comment: For the headers that you're currently sending, what do they look like? (from http, not code I mean)